# How to correctly register service for .NET 6 WPF application for single-file publish?

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-6.0

I have the following piece of code in a .NET 6 WPF application:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddDrugVerificationModule(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<DrugVerificationApi>();
    services.AddTransient<TestDrugVerificationApi>();
    services.AddTransient<IDrugVerificationService, DrugVerificationService>();

    services.AddTransient<IDrugVerificationApi>(provider =>
        provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<VerificationOptions>>().Value.UseTestVerification
            ? provider.GetRequiredService<TestDrugVerificationApi>()
            : provider.GetRequiredService<DrugVerificationApi>());

    return services;
}
```

This is happening before building the service provider.

Problem: when I publish the application as a single-file, I get the error:

[image: error]

Everything works if application is published as non-single-file.

Question: how do I properly register services for a single-file application?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was pass a VerificationOptions variable into this method and registered the DrugVerificationApi or TestDrugVerificationApi class depending on the parameters options.UseTestVerification.